# Changed network connection for Windows server running on Google Cloud and can't connect

Tags: windows-server-2012, ip, google-cloud-platform, static-ip

So I changed the IP for my windows server 2012 running on Google Cloud Platform in network sharing center and "tab" the subnet mask which was 255.0.0.0 and I got disconnected from the server and I can't reconnect!

Is it possible to get the auto IP again?

Answer (score 1):

You can use interactive access to your Windows serial console to fix this issue. For this purpose, using [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/), go to `Compute Engine`, then `VM instances`, edit your Windows VM and `Enable connecting to serial ports`. Save the changes.

Then click on the small arrow next to `Connect to serial port` button and select `Port 2`. This should open serial console window as depicted below. Run `help` command and you will see a list of commands that you can use. Using `i` command, you can set back/configure your network settings.

For more information, visit [this article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console).

[image]

Answer (score -1):

So somehow I got it. I changed the IPv4 by using the meta data inside the google cloud, made it to a static "private IP" and I was able to connect to my server and changed the IP from inside the server